# UnauthorizedAccessException when writing text file to C:\ on Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, file-io, uac

I have recently moved to Windows 7. Now my .NET application fails writing log file to C:\

My TraceListener is throwing the exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

What to do? I am running application from the studio and so I think it must inherit all my rights and I am the admin on my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have UAC enabled you won't be able to write files to `C:\`, even if you're admin, unless you start the program in elevated mode to activate the admin privileges.

Files shouldn't really be placed in the root of `C:`, so the best is to create a subdirectory and give yourself access rights (to your account, not the administrators group). If you really want to have the file on `C:\` and not run it as elevated, you can use Windows Explorer to grant yourself (your account, not the administrators group) write access to `C:\`.

Comment: UAC works by disabling your admin rights, until you activate them. It's a security measure to prevent malicious programs to modify sensitive system files. Default settings on Windows 7 is to have it enabled. More details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

Comment: If you don't know what is UAC, maybe you should learn a bit more about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will need to run with the required permissions. Only those with Administrator access can write to 'special' folders such as the system drive and so the application will need to execute initially with elevated privileges.

See [here](http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-2/), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186212%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for information on security permissions in code.

Comment: fixing this by running elevated is the wrong approach. Logging somewhere else is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have UAC still turned on.

You will need to indicate in your app.config, that you want the process to use elevated rights.

The default generated app.config have that info.

Comment: Oh, where is that option in config?

Comment: not in the app.config but in your manifest. However running the application elevated just so you can log in the root of C is overkill